# C/C++ How Nested Structures Are Packed?

Tags: struct, nested, padding, memory-alignment, packing

If a word is 4 bytes on my architecture, I would expect the following structure to be padded in order to be at least a word (4 bytes) in size.

```
// 4 bytes
struct
{
  uint8_t High : 4;
  uint8_t Low : 4;
} Value;
```

Now, let's say I have the following nested structure:

```
// ? bytes
struct
{
  uint8_t Address;
  struct
  {
    uint8_t High : 4;
    uint8_t Low : 4;
  } Value;
} Register;
```

How will this structure be packed? Will `Value` remain a word (4 bytes) in size? There are two ways I'm expecting this structure to be packed but I don't know which one is right or if even one is. Let's say `R` sand for `Register`, `A` is the member `Address` and `V` is the member `Value`. The two ways I can think of are:

First:

```
    Byte1 Byte2 Byte3 Byte4 Byte5 Byte6 Byte7 Byte8
R =     A     0     0     0     V     0     0     0
```

Second:

```
    Byte1 Byte2 Byte3 Byte4
R =     A     V     0     0
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This structure is packed the following way:

```
    Byte1 Byte2 Byte3 Byte4
R =     A     V     0     0
```